# Scrollbars Gone in PrimeFaces 13

Tags: jsf, primefaces, scrollbar, primefaces-extensions

I'm heading up our project team's migration from PrimeFaces 6 to PrimeFaces 13, and it looks like the normal vertical scrollbar which appears when the user zooms in too closely, no longer appears.  I've looked into scroll panels and overflow properties in divs, but they don't behave the same as a whole screen scroll bar.

I tried adding "overflow" properties to divs, and I tried creating scrollPanels.  Neither produced the same behavior a page scrollbar provides.

Our content page didn't have or need any special code to enable scrolling under PrimeFaces 6.  Is there a way to accomplish this in PrimeFaces 13?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] see https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: I assume you are using an old jQuery ThemeRoller theme from 6?  Those are deprecated and you will have to move to a supported theme like the built in Saga, Arya, Vela themes.   You are probbaly missing CSS or have invalid CSS for PF13 with your old ThemeRoller theme?

Comment: I have been using "smoothness".  I have tried switching to "saga" and "vela", and still the issue persists.  Interestingly though, in "vela" theme, which is decidedly darker than the others, when I open my zoomed-in screen, I see a vertical scrollbar flash on, then disappear, so it's apparently there, but is somehow disabled.  Does any of this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a pe:layoutPane resolved my issue. I had never heard of one of those, but apparently, they're needed in PF13 in order to enable vertical scrollbars when screens overflow.

Comment: That's not true. Your problem was caused by something else beyond PrimeFaces. You should have created a [mcve] in order for us to point out that.

Comment: I created a reproducer [here](https://github.com/NCIDevRonR/primefaces-test/tree/no-vertical-scrollbar), and another user talked me through adding a pe:layoutPane, which resolved my scrollbar issue a couple commits ago.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to Primefaces Extensions Layout component.

it has these styles.

```css
.pe-layout-pane-content {
    padding: 6px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The `overflow:auto` is what causes the scrollbar to appear or not.  Something in your setup is causing that style to be overridden because in F12 Chrome tools if I disable `overflow:auto` my scrollbars dissappear as described in your behavior.

[image]